# Twig Error Runtime When Using Conditionals

Tags: templating, conditional

I am trying to create a meta include to display all my meta data and I have the following set up so far:

```
3. {% if craft.request.getSegment(1) != "404" and craft.request.getSegment(1) != "databytes" %}
  4. <title>{% if entry.metaTitle is defined %}{{ entry.metaTitle }}{% else %}{{ entry.title }}{% endif %} | {{ siteName }}</title>
  5. {% if entry.metaDescription is defined %}
  6. <meta name="description" content="{{ entry.metaDescription }}">
  7. {% endif %}
8. {% endif %}

{# 404 =============== #}

{% if craft.request.getSegment(1)  == "404" %}
  <title>Page Missing | {{ siteName }}</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Sorry the page you are looking for is missing, it may have been moved or deleted, please use the navigation to search for similar content.">
{% endif %}
```

If I visit main pages the code works and if I go to example.com/404 the code works, but if I visit an invalid url example.com/foo then I get a Twig Error Runtime error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Craft doesn't redirect to 404 if a page isn't found, it just loads the 404 template and keeps the invalid uri.

**What currently happens:**

- example.com/invalid_uri
- Craft doesn't find it and shows the 404 template
- Your conditional checks if `404` is in the uri, but it isn't.
- Your code now tries to access the `entry` variable which isn't defined.
- This results in a Twig error.

.

**Solution:**

Add an `entry is defined` to your conditional:

```
{% if craft.request.getSegment(1) != "404" and craft.request.getSegment(1) != "databytes" and entry is defined %}
....
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That did it Victor thank you, for info I also needed to add `or entry is not defined` to the last 404 conditional which makes sense with what you have explained.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at what you have in your *_includes/_page_meta* file at line 4.

Most likely you just need to wrap it in a conditional with `is defined` like

```
{% if entry is defined %}
    {# your template stuff here #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I think Victor's answer is better!

Comment: Thanks Alex, yes Victor's solution fixed it (I added the line numbers in to try and help to).